# Why am I being told that a non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context?

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jframe, jbutton

I'm creating a button which, when clicked, will go directly to a website. But my code has an error. The error says a non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("JLinkButton");
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add("Center", new AnotherLinkButton("www.google.com"));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocation(100, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

Comment: Always post the line that gives the error message and the complete message.

Comment: sorry..here's the line:  frame.getContentPane().add("Center", new AnotherLinkButton("www.google.com"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code looks fine assuming `AnotherLinkButton` is defined correctly.

You probably have code like this:

```
class Main {
    class AnotherLinkButton {
    }
}
```

To create an instance of `AnotherLinkButton`, you need an instance of `Main`. Try this instead:

```
class Main {
    static class AnotherLinkButton {
    }
}
```

That makes `AnotherLinkButton` independent of `Main`.

Comment: +1 He probably defined `AnotherLinkButton` with `class` instead of `static class`.

Comment: @Aaron, possibly, but I think that would give a different error message.  I would guess that the AnotherLinkButton has a constructor or something else that is truly causing the issue.

Comment: If the class is an inner class of the main class, it gets a non-static field with a reference to the main class - which isn't available in the static context. Hence the error.

Comment: @Aaron, just tested it. I see this error instead `No enclosing instance of type X is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type X (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of X).`

Comment: Do you use the same Java version as steph22?